# calling a client side function

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code needs to call function `cleanSerializedArray();` in header.js which is defined in main.js, both files are under the client directory.

Browser console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: cleanSerializedArray is not defined

But when the definition is moved to the same file "header.js", the console says

> undefined

Why are those 2 un expected results, I expected to see the function work in both cases? Thanks

```
'use strict';
Template.header.events({
  'click .mainMenu': function () {
    //control the footer visibility
    if (Session.get('showMainMenu')) {
      Session.set('showMainMenu', false);
    } else {
      console.log(cleanSerializedArray()); //<------- called
      //Meteor.call('storeUserInputs', objArray);
      Session.set('showMainMenu', true);
    }
});

function cleanSerializedArray() {
   return $('form').serializeArray().forEach(function (item) {
    item.value = item.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
  });
}
```

Comment: Was the function defined globally? Javascript looks fine, so I assume it's something scope related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `undefined` because [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) always returns `undefined`.
You probably want to change your `cleanSerializedArray` function to this:

```
function cleanSerializedArray() {
    var array = $('form').serializeArray();
    array.forEach(function (item) {
        item.value = item.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
    });
    return array;
}
```

As for your `ReferenceError`, that is usually caused by one of two things:

Scoping:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    function myFunc(){ /* ... */ }

    /* some code that uses myFunc */
});
/* myFunc is not available out here */
```

Timing:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    window.myFunc = function(){ /* ... */ }

    /* some code that uses myFunc */
});
/* myFunc is not available yet */
```

Since you seem to be calling the function only from an event handler, a scoping issue is far more likely than a timing one.
Try declaring the function instead as:

```
window.cleanSerializedArray = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Refactoring the function and fixing the scope fixed the problem. In regards to the scope, doesn't Meteor look after it?

Comment: @FredJ. I have no experience with Meteor at all, but as long as you're still running JavaScript, you're bound to the rules and properties of JavaScript. And it looks to me like Meteor isn't its own language (yet).